# How to pass a string as stdin to a job?

Tags: external-command, async

I have a shell command which reads from stdin, processes the input, and writes to stdout.  To call it synchronously from vim I can do `system('mycommand', data)` where `data` is some string my vimscript has prepared.

What's the equivalent way to pass `data` to stdin using `job_start()` / `jobstart()`?

Update: in this case I'm particularly interested in the answer for neovim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim:

```
let job = job_start(...)
let channel = job_getchannel(job)
call ch_sendraw(channel, data)
call ch_close_in(channel)
```

NeoVim:

```
let jobid = jobstart(...)
call chansend(jobid, data)
call chanclose(jobid, 'stdin')
```